# Storing Selected CheckedListBox Values in Database

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I have two tables in my database. Let's say table A and table B. table A values are put in checkedlistbox. The selected values in checkedlistbox then are put into table B. I tried to make a code however it wont work. Do you have any idea on how to make this problem work?

thanks ahead guys.

by the way im using c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Npgsql;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form8 : Form
    {
        public Form8()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += Form8_Load;
            button2.Click += button2_Click;
        }

        private void Form8_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstring = ("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=021393;Database=postgres;");
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT conname FROM condition", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).DataSource = dt;
                ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).DisplayMember = "conname";
                ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).DisplayMember = "conid";
                string[] condition = dt.Rows[0]["conname"].ToString().Split(',');
            }

        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstring = ("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=021393;Database=postgres;");
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into famhistory(famid) Values (@famid)", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@famid", checkedListBox1.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved");
            conn.Close();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code that didn't work.

Comment: although it works but only 1 value is stored in the database. i wanted it to have multiple values. how will i do it?

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstring = ("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=021393;Database=postgres;");
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into famhistory(famid) Values (@famid)", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@famid", checkedListBox1.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved");
            conn.Close();

        }

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? do you get some exception?

Comment: i dont get any exception and it works however only 1 value is stored in database. i wanted to store as many as it can depending on how many are there on the checkedlistbox.

Comment: But you pass only one string into the query?

Comment: You're passing only one item in your query, loop over the selected items and call the query for every item

Comment: you can do it like this - insert into TABLENAME (COLUMNNAME) values (VALUE1), values (VALUE2) here value1 value2 are selected values , or you can use a foreach loop for all selected items collection and then inserting data one by one but that would mean unnecessary overhead.

Comment: use List<string> to store the selected items.

Comment: @learningNew     what if the user wants to update the values in checkedlistbox? example he wants to add 5 more medical conditions because a certain patient has 5 conditions in his family history which is not included on checkedlistbox.

Comment: @Shaharyar i tried to loop it but it wont work.

Comment: Provide textboxes or any other control and use list.Add(textbox.Text) to add them to list, after adding items from selected items from checkbox. Then loop over list items to insert values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through all the selected items:

```
//check if any item is selected
if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    //connect to database
    string connstring = ("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=021393;Database=postgres;");
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
    conn.Open();

    //loop through all selected items
    foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        //convert item to string
        string checkedItem = item.ToString();

        //insert item to database
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into famhistory(famid) Values (@famid)", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@famid", checkedItem); //add item
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    //close connection
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved");
}
```

Note: I am executing all insert commands in one open connection, because opening and closing connection frequently is not best practice.

Comment: Then write a `StoredProcedure` which checks if it already exists in the table, do not insert